# Свой стиль кода в phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

На работе используется стандарт форматирования, импортируется как xml в шторм. Дома такого нет, я могу, конечно с работы взять, но это не дело, т.к. пилю свой проект, лучше свое сделать, чем с работы воровать. Такой вопрос - есть ли какая-нибудь документация относительно написания этой xml-ки для jetbrains IDE? В инете вижу только ссылки на документацию по шторму относительно того, как импортировать стиль в IDE, а как его писать не сказано (по крайней мере я не нашел)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала идём

`Settings` → `Editor` → `Code Style` → `PHP` (JS и пр) и настраиваем все галочки во всех вкладках по-вкусу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для экспорта можно нажать там же на `Scheme` → `Import export`

---

Так же можно настроить инспекцию:

`Settings` → `Editor` → `Inspections` → `PHP`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогает в шторме с подсказками справа от кода

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, до вашего ответа уже нашел что где и как, хотел ответить на свой вопрос а тут ответ. Файл, кстати, можно сформировать из шторма, тап по шестеренке и экспорт (там можно выбрать, либо .editorConfig , либо xml формат).

Comment: Ну если ответ полезен - галочку тык!)